# about my collision detection

Tags: ios

ok first of all here is my code ..

```
-(IBAction)handlePan : (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer

{ CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];

[self checkCollison];

}

-(void) checkCollison
{

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Dot.frame, CollisionImage.frame))

{

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(playSoundId);
}


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSURL *SoundURL = [ NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]            pathForResource:@"beep"ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, & playSoundId);

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

what I've been trying to do for EVER is having Dot.center to stop when it collide .. i don't want the screen to flip or alert to show or images disseapear or all of those that people show everywhere .. i got that one .. all i want is my image to act as a wall .. like a maze i just want Dot to stop going thru the other image and just stop there ...not stop the game.. i want a wall but it seem to be so hard to do because i can't find the right answer ANYWHERE .. all people are suggesting is something to happen when images collide .. please help lol

Comment: I'm tottaly new in all that by the way..

Comment: So you want the gesture recogniser to stop, or the dot to not be able to move in the direction of the wall any more?

Comment: i kinda want both of those 2 ! my game is like a maze so all i want is to make sure that the player can't go thru the "wall" or object in this case  i don't want "dot" to go thru "collisionImage". collision image for now is just and rectangle in the middle of my screen and dot is ..well its a dot lol

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're moving your view based on the gesture recogniser, *then* checking for a collision. You need to add some sort of feedback mechanism so that the position isn't allowed to change if a collision happens.

Lets also assume that you'd like the user to keep their finger on the screen so that the dot will keep moving after a collision, it just can't go through the boundary.

I'd do something like:

- Change the check collision method to return a BOOL - YES if a collision has occurred. You'll probably want to not call the beep from here as it might happen too often.
- Save the center of the view at the start of your gesture recogniser method
- Try to do the movement
- If a collision occurs, set the position back again, and try it just on the x-axis. If no collision occurs, leave it. If a collision occurs, try it on the y-axis. If no collision occurs, leave it.
- If any collision occurred, play the beep

This should allow you to, for example, hit the wall on your left but keep sliding up it by moving your finger.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed help i appreciate it ! But like i said im new to that so any idea on where i can go to learn how to do it ? Thanks again !!